# How to charge my client for Google Cloud usage without free tier?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am hosting a website and a few other elements on Google Cloud platform for a client. Very soon, I will host other services for another client.

What bother me is that I am currently under free tier and Google tell me that for the client's project I have to pay 0€ (which is nice by the way). But by adding a new project I will exceed this free tier.

My questions are :

- Will my first client be charged 0€ (because of free tier) and my second client his real usage (because free tier is exceeded)?
- Can I get the cost my clients would pay **if I was not** on free tier?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will my first client be charged 0€ (because of free tier) and my
>   second client his real usage (because free tier is exceeded)?

For google they really don't care about your clients, you just have to pay them per usage of VM's/services used, if you have exceeded 300$ limit ( which is in Canada) example in a month. you just have to pay them for whatever is exceeding that limit. Whether it is your old project or it is new project.

> Can I get the cost my clients would pay if I was not on free tier?

Google console will tell you cost of each VM used with what is cost of per CPU with cost of each stoarge pheriphals used etc for each service used ( i.e. how much I/O used for that VM) . 
It is very easy to figure out from bill. what is cost of each VM used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in my Google Console, it show me 0€ cost because usage is included in free tier (not the 300€), so it is not possible to get the "real" cost...

Comment: Did you get any of your bill .. , when you get your bill, it will tell you exact cost & then it apply free tier discount. So don't worry you will get bill.